# Double actions in Libreoffice when Control pressed

Tags: kubuntu, kde, libreoffice

On version 7.0.3.1 of Libreoffice on Kubuntu 20.10 (sys info below), actions with "Ctrl" pressed are doubled, so I cannot make anything bold by pressing Ctrl+B as the action is immediatelly undone. Pressing Ctrl+V pastes the contents of the clipboard twice.

I've seen this asked (with no answer) here: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/280599/double-actions-when-control-is-pressed/

And here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=260689 - and while it is marked as solved there, that solution has not worked for me at all.

Libreoffice is the only application affected.

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.19.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.74.0
Qt Version: 5.14.2
Kernel Version: 5.8.0-33-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 6 × AMD Ryzen 5 3500X 6-Core Processor
Memory: 15.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: GeForce GT 710/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: The bigger picture from the archlinux solution seemed to me that the poster of that problem ran Gnome programs in a KDE environment (specifically Onboard). Might that be your issue as well? Did you run the `systemctl` command listed there?

Comment: I did, and I was not running (nor do I often run) gnome programs. And I did not have a virtual keyboard installed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue by wondering what was it that I had installed recently that could run in the background and possibly cause this issue.

It turns out that it was Warsaw, a program required by Brazilian banks to grant access to accounts in desktop computers.

I uninstalled it and the problem's gone so far. However, I reckon this is only a partial answer, because it is not enough for people who would like to keep Warsaw installed in their machines. It would be better if someone understood by what mechanism Warsaw is interacting with Libreoffice of all things and causing the issue - hopefully someone will, cause I can't atm.